# How to approach this question? Am I right?

Tags: group-theory

I have been asked to show that $SL(2,\mathbb{R})$ is a subgroup of $GL(2,\mathbb{R})$.  The latter consists of $2\times 2$ real matrices with nonzero determinants, considered as a group under matrix multiplication.  The former "special linear group" is the subset of these with determinant $1$.

Here are my thoughts:

Let $A,B \in SL(2,R)$

then $\det (A) = \det (B) = 1$

$\det (AB^{-1}) = 1$

Comment: Why don't you just write the question in MathJax ?

Comment: If you are trying to prove that it is a subgroup, then you also need to show that it is nonempty.

Comment: @ritwiksinha: Because not everyone knows TeX formatting.

Answer (score 1):

You need to show it is a subgroup.  So it is non-empty because $\det(I_2)=1$ so the identity is in there.  If $\det(A)=\det(B)=1$, then $\det(AB)=\det(A)\det(B)=1\cdot 1=1$, so it is closed.  If $\det(A)=1$, then since $A\cdot A^{-1}=I_2$, we have $\det(A)\det(A^{-1})=\det(AA^{-1})=\det(I_2)=1$, but that means $1\cdot \det(A^{-1})=1$, so $\det(A^{-1})=1$ and thus the subset is closed under inverses and is therefore a subgroup.